# deserialize json using jackson with dynamic field name

Tags: jackson

I'm trying to deserialize json using jackson, the problem is that field names are not always the same, for instance

One call will give me

```
{
  id: "blabla"
  aFieldname : { an object if type A} 
}

Another call will give me 

{
  id: "blabla"
  anotherName : { the same kind of object } 
}
```

I can't predict the name of the field. is it even possible ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could deserialize the JSON as a `Map<String, Object>`:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>> typeReference = 
    new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>>() {};
Map<String, Object> data = mapper.readValue(json, typeReference);
```

---

Or you could use [`@JsonAnySetter`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAnySetter.html):

```java
public class Data {

    private String id;
    private Map<String, Object> unknownFields = new HashMap<>();

    // Getters and setters (except for unknownFields)

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setUnknownField(String name, Object value) {
        unknownFields.put(name, value);
    }
}
```

---

If you know the *possible names* of the property, you could use the [`@JsonAlias`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9.pr1/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAlias.html) annotation, which was [introduced in Jackson 2.9](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/wiki/Jackson-Release-2.9):

```java
public class Data {

    private String id;

    @JsonAlias({ "onePossibleName", "anotherPossibleName" })
    private Foo something;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

Comment: yes I could but it does not looks nice, trying to find a better way

Comment: Very nice ! I like the @JsonAnySetter but what happen if you have two unknown fields of the same type ?

Comment: @Seb Give it a try. _Spoiler: you'll have two entries in the map._