# Serializing JSON object containing nested objects with dynamic property names with Jackson

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I have been struggling with this, and I can't seem to get it right. I have a Java Spring Boot project and I need to create an API that returns the following JSON in what I called `AggregatedResponse`:

```
  {
    "shipments": {
      "987654321": ["BOX", "BOX", "PALLET"]
    },
    "track": {
      "123456789": "COLLECTING"
    },
    "pricing": {
      "NL": 14.242090605778
      "CN": 20.503467806384
    }
}
```

Each of the objects (shipments, track, pricing) need to be fetched from an external API.
This means that I need to create the `AggregatedResponse` and use a setter whenever I'm receiving the different data from the external APIs.

The number in the `shipments` (987654321) comes from the request param passed to the external API that retrieves shipments. The track number (123456789) also comes from an external API.

This is the Java structure I have so far:

```
public class AggregatedResponse {
    private TrackResponse tracking;
    private ShipmentsResponse shipments;
    private PricingResponse pricing;

    public ShipmentsResponse getShipments() {
        return shipments;
    }

    public void setShipmentsResponse(ShipmentsResponse value) {
        this.shipments = value;
    }

    public TrackResponse getTrackResponse() {
        return tracking;
    }

    public void setTrackResponse(TrackResponse trackResponse) {
        this.tracking = trackResponse;
    }

    public PricingResponse getPricing() {
        return pricing;
    }

    public void setPricing(PricingResponse value) {
        this.pricing = value;
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that like I mentioned, the `shipments` and `track` JSON object have dynamic names, so I have tried different strategies for creating the `TrackResponse` and the `ShipmentsResponse`.

How could I do this?

Comment: Possibly https://stackoverflow.com/a/51079922/6487148

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Map from the data instead of class so you can define the keys and serialize it.